# Python 2.7 cannot import Crypto

Tags: python, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, keyczar

Hi this what I'm getting when I try to run a python program on Windows 8x64 Visual Studio 2012 Python 2.7 I've tried installing precompiled binaries but failed.

```
 from keyczar.keys import RsaPrivateKey,RsaPublicKey,AesKey
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keyczar\keys.py", line 34, in <module>
 from Crypto.Cipher import AES
  ImportError: No module named Crypto.Cipher
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question already, but check if the precompiled packages comes with the pyCrypto package. As mentioned here; https://code.google.com/p/keyczar/wiki/PythonDependencies